# 缓解 vs. 缓和 - are the true synonyms/同义词?

Tags: word-choice

So, one can 缓解压力 and one can 缓和紧张局势. Can you 缓和压力 or 缓解紧张局势?
If not, why not? :-) I guess if you say it enough, it becomes true, right? 
Many thanks,
Hashamyim (incidentally, not my real name lol)

Comment: for answer see online dictionaries, esp. usage examples, esp.bkrs：缓和  #6253 1) v. relax; ease up; mitigate; appease
他试图缓和紧张的气氛。 He tried to ease the tension.
2) n. détente; calm; moderate; mild, much more!

缓解 #4693
huạ̌njiě
1) mitigate; alleviate; ease; relieve
他的病情有些缓解。 His illness eased a bit.
2) relax,  much more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough《规范》has a note on its entry for 缓解 that says:

> 注意 跟“缓和”不同。“缓解”侧重指“减轻”或“使减轻”; “缓和”侧重指“平和”或“使平和”。

A rough translation:

Note: it is different from “缓和”. “缓解” emphasizes alleviation or mitigation; “缓和” highlights “calming” or  “mildness.”

**Oxford** provides some examples that we can compare:

> 缓解食品短缺状况 
>   alleviate the food shortage
>
> 缓解痛苦 
>   allay a pain

and

> 缓和紧张局势 
>   relax the tension
>
> 形势有所缓和。 
>   Things have eased up a bit.